# Regex for date and and finding BP values simultaneously

Tags: python, regex, data-extraction

I have unstructured data where I have to extract BP values and the dates(having different formats) as shown below. Right now I have a regex function to extract Bp values. I have a specific case as highlighted in the picture where consecutive dates and even single encountered dates have to be extracted(Not DOB).

[image]

Currently, the code I have gives only the BP values. I want the regex function for Bp and extracting the dates as well simultaneously.

I have attached the regex code below.

```
regex = r'\b(?:BP:?(?:-Sitting)?|Blood Pressure) \d+/\d+(?: \d+/\d+|  \d+/\d+)*(?: sm| -Lw| cB| Jr|\
    -aA| cs| -ic| ic| -RG|  kA| -sL| BL| kc| am| -sH| sH| es| ts| np| 8s| ca| Pm| JE| so| cp| v8| Eu| -cp|\
    Pm| EB| Fr| -Fr| -ms| -LN| -mT| -mk| -GF| -HO| Jp| wD| 8m| mc| -mc| Yr| -Lp| -ml| -LA| s/d| -aA| s/d|mmHg| mm Hg|\
    mm hg.|.?)?|B/P - (?:Sys|Dias)tolic \d+|(?:Sys|Dias)tolic Blood Pressure \d+ \w+\b'
```

The image of the current output is given below, in which dates are not included.
[image]

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option is to add matching an optional `/` and 1 or more digits in the part where you match the `\d+/\d+`.

You can shorten this part `\d+/\d+(?: \d+/\d+|  \d+/\d+)*` to `\d+/\d+(?: ?\d+/\d+)*` as the only difference is matching 1 or 2 spaces in the alternation.

Adding matching an optional forward slash and 1 or more digits in the first part and in the repetition would look like `\d+/\d+(?:/\d+)?(?:  ?\d+/\d+(?:/\d+)?)*`

The updated pattern:

```
\b(?:BP:?(?:-Sitting)?|Blood Pressure) \d+/\d+(?:/\d+)?(?:  ?\d+/\d+(?:/\d+)?)*(?: sm| -Lw| cB| Jr|\
    -aA| cs| -ic| ic| -RG|  kA| -sL| BL| kc| am| -sH| sH| es| ts| np| 8s| ca| Pm| JE| so| cp| v8| Eu| -cp|\
    Pm| EB| Fr| -Fr| -ms| -LN| -mT| -mk| -GF| -HO| Jp| wD| 8m| mc| -mc| Yr| -Lp| -ml| -LA| s/d| -aA| s/d|mmHg| mm Hg|\
    mm hg.)?|B/P - (?:Sys|Dias)tolic \d+|(?:Sys|Dias)tolic Blood Pressure \d+ \w+\b
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/fI9R5G/1)

Note that I have omitted the `.?` at the end of the alternation, as it would match a trailing whitespace char as well.

Comment: What about the third marked row? In the demo I don't see it. Will this work for that case as well?

Comment: @Shiva These are the matches https://regex101.com/r/9Gvn3k/1 Or if you want to match all the numbers https://regex101.com/r/hVQbNU/1

Comment: In the 3rd row, the encounter date has to be matched as well, along with the Bp value.

Comment: @Shiva You could for example match a date like format and assert that there is not `DOB ` before it https://regex101.com/r/hftVxU/1 Or optionally match it for the whole part https://regex101.com/r/iYb9vR/1

Comment: Yes. It worked very well. Thank you very much @Thefourthbird